# Учебники начальной школы

Tags: обучение

Я сейчас в 6 классе. Захотел повторить программу по русскому языку начальной школы отсюда из-за большого выбора учебников возник вопрос. Можете порекомендовать лучшие учебники по русскому языку с 1 по 4 класс?

Answer (score 1):

В 5 классе вы повторяли всё, что изучали в начальной школе, так что возьмите лучше учебник для 5 класса, обратив особенное внимание на безударную гласную корня. В конце учебника есть словарь-справочник "Пиши правильно". Нужно выучить написание всех словарных слов оттуда, повторить чередующуюся гласную. Неплохо повторить и все сведения о существительном, в начальной школе обо всём этом поверхностный материал.

Comment: То есть абсолютно все темы проходившиеся с 1-4 класс повторяются в большинстве учебников в 5 классе? И по сути имеет смысл пройти какой-то только один учебник 5 класса?

Comment: Именно. И, конечно, внимательно слушать учителя в 6-м, чтобы усвоить новый материал.